# OTRS automatically ticket generate

Tags: linux

I am using OTRS last 5 month without any problem but currently facing problem to automatic ticket generate. in the log showing below error.

and from tail -f /var/log/httpd/error_log, we are getting below log:

```
ERROR: OTRS-CGI-92 Perl: 5.16.3 OS: linux Time: Sat Dec  9 17:05:31 2017

Message: Module Kernel/System/Ticket/Custom.pm not in @INC (/opt/otrs/Custom /opt/otrs/Kernel/cpan-lib /opt/otrs/ /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd)
```

Note: When we select manually from GUI its creating ticket but it should me created automatically.

Please let me know if needed any further info

Answer (score 0):

This error message means that the file Kernel/System/Ticket/Custom.pm can not be found on your disk.

Usually this comes from a SysConfig setting which you can enable. It's called "Ticket::CustomModule###001-CustomModule" and can be found via Admin -> SysConfig -> Group: Ticket -> SubGroup: 001-CustomModule

Just disable it again.

By the way, we used OTRS several years but we had many agent complains about the UI and complexity of OTRS. So we stumbled over Zammad (https://zammad.com). It's new, easy to use, for all exists a REST API and open source too (https://zammad.org). Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Hi Mr. Hans,
After changed the setting as you mentions. Its working properly.
 thanks again for your support.